# Is my WPF UserControl being leaked through something I am doing wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, red-gate-ants, ants

This is the first time I have used a profiler and thus also my first time for the ANTs Memory Profiler.

I have set up a test to isolated 2 user controls (written by me) on a test window called "WindowTest"

On WindowTest there is a user control DBDocComment. Within DBDocComment there is second user control but it is not appearing in the image. I am simply opening WindowTest from the main window and then closing it.

The thing that I am seeing but do not understand is indicated in the image. After WindowTest is closed I would consider that a reference to my user control DBDocComment should not be hanging around, but it is.

Can someone help me out here or please and point me in a direction to help me see what is going on.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you add some code. There is no way to find out what you have missed unless you do so.

Comment: I would love to. What would you like? I have a feeling that to an experienced person the image says it all. and whilst they might not be able to answer it they will direct me as to where to look.

Comment: Try dotMemory profiler from JetBrains, it has bunch of automatic inspections most of them for WPF. Also it can show simple graph of retention. My experience of profiling WPF apps is more optimistic with dotMemory.

Comment: Thanks Roman. I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested a number of memory profilers such as ANTs Memory Profiler and came to the conclusion that they all looked great but I could not understand what was going on.

I believe that the answer to the above question is that it is not a leak. It appears that there are many false positives which are very hard to understand.